# Split foreach loop results over multiple columns

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently listing all my interests inside one div. However, I'd like to spread these across columns. So have 4 interests per column. How can I change my CSS to allow this?

```
          <?php
          $interests = get_terms('interests',array( 'taxonomy' => 'interests' )); 
          foreach($interests as $term){
              echo '<li>'.$term->name.'</li>';
          }
          ?>
```

Preferred HTML output:

```
            <div class="columns">

                <ul>
                    <li>F1</li>
                    <li>Cycling</li>
                    <li>Football</li>
                    <li>Rugby</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="columns">

                <ul>
                    <li>Running</li>
                    <li>Swimming</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
      $interests = get_terms('interests',array( 'taxonomy' => 'interests' )); 
      echo '<div class="columns">';
      $index = 0;
      foreach($interests as $term){
          if ($index > 0 and $index % 4 == 0) {
              //if not the first row and dividable by 4
              echo '</div><div class="columns">';
          }
          echo '<li>'.$term->name.'</li>';
          $index++;
      }
      echo '</div>';
  ?>
```

For you comment:

```
$interests = get_terms('interests',array( 'taxonomy' => 'interests' )); 

$count = count($interests);
$numItemsPerRow = ceil($count / 3);

//we need this in case of 2-1-1 for example, otherwise you get 2-2
$numItemsOffsetFix = $count % 3 == 1;

$index  = 0;
echo '<div class="columns">';
foreach($interests as $term){
    if ($index > 0 and $index % $numItemsPerRow == 0) {
        echo '</div><div class="columns">';
        if ($numItemsOffsetFix) {
            $numItemsPerRow--;
            $numItemsOffsetFix = false;
        }
    }
    echo '<li>'.$term->name.'</li>';
    $index++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Excellent!
I also wonder, if I plan to use standard 3 columns, is there a way to spread these results out over 3 columns? So if I retrieve 4 results. The first column would have 2 results, the 2nd 1 and the 3rd 1. I imagine this may be complicated :-D